# Adding external project to unity solution

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to add an external project to my unity solution.
It works fine using mono develop but whenever I switch back to unity it seems to remove the reference from the solution.

Is there a way to prevent unity from doing this ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 14):

Unity rebuilds (i.e., removes the existing file and build it again from scratch) `MyProject.sln` file whenever it finds changes from `~/Assets` folder. As such, any manual modification done by you or outside Unity's automated process on `MyProject.sln` will be discarded each time Unity compiles.

As @Kamalen mentioned, the usual way to import an *external* project is to have the external project be a library project, build *.dll from it, and put the *.dll file somewhere under `~/Assets`. When there are *.dll files under `~/Assets`, you have a reference to the classes and methods defined in the library file from any code you put under `~/Assets`.

However, it seems that you have the access to the source code and tend to modify the external project often from your comment.

In that case, you could consider putting the source code of the external project under `~/Assets`. The folder structure would then look like:

```
MyProject/
MyProject/MyProject.sln  // this is rebuilt again each time by Unity
MyProject/Assets/
MyProject/Assets/ExternalProject/...  // This could be a git submodule
MyProject/Assets/scripts/...
```

You can of course have the `ExternalProject` be a git submodule and maintain it as a separate git repo. Then you can either make changes to the `ExternalProject` from inside Untiy folder, or the original location of `ExternalProject` and then sync the `ExternalProject` under Unity folder with a pull from git.

As a rule of thumb, import *.dll files if you know the library is complete and it is unlikely to have changes in the library project, which includes the case when you do not have access to its source code. When there exist *.dll files in a project, it's common to assume the library is complete, unlikely to change, and outside of our control, and hence it's called an ***external*** project.

Comment: Thanks Matthias, Should proably not used the term "external to" talk about a piece of code that I've coded myself. Yes I have access to the source code of the project since it is mine. It's the middle and thus shared tier of my 3 tiers app for which unity is the client. This coded is shared between the client (unity) and the server. I designed already a wpf client and the shared (common) code is simply added into the client solution. Hence the reason why I am surprised it is to difficult to add code to unity coming from an external project.

Comment: I tried this out and ran into a few problems.  I know it's been 1.5 years, so things may have changed, but thought I'd comment anyways.  Within my external projects, some projects reference others.  This causes unity to complain that there are two of the same dlls.  It looks like it pulls the dlls directly from the bin folder.  On top of that, it does not like anything in AssemblyInfo.  The easiest solution to that problem is to get rid of AssemblyInfo, or enclose them in a #if block.  In a related note, Jetbrains Rider is able to step into the dlls without problem.  I can't get VS to do that.

Comment: @Nikhil Yeah time has passed and I may have to double check but... are you making sure your external dll files are having unique file names and are different from the default dll files Unity would create? After you generate dlls, place them anywhere under the Assets folder. After compilation, you should be able to access to the classes of the dlls from any source code in the Unity project with proper using statements to the namespaces.

Comment: Yes, the names are unique.  Are you saying I should change the output directory of all my External projects to the same directory?  Like Assets/Libs/?

Answer (score 5):

Your best way to have an external project into Unity is to... not have an external project directly. Unity does rebuild the solution file regulary and is almost like a temporary file.

What you can do is configure your external project as a library project, and configure the project (or an external tool) to output the generated DLL in any subfolder of the Assets folder.

If your external project uses Unity classes, it will need to have references to UnityEngine.dll and UnityEditor.dll, located in folders :

- Applications/Unity.app/Contents/Frameworks/Managed/UnityEngine.dll for Mac
- Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Managed\UnityEngine.dll for Windows

Comment: Thanks,

Not ideal at all :( whenever I want to modify the external project, I need to rebuild it then.

Not ideal indeed !

Comment: Is there a way for Unity to detect if that DLL is out of date (or non existant) and trigger the external build?

Comment: I dont think so, Unity cannot know that the external code has changed in this way. Note that this question is really outdated ; Unity has since come with a way better way of handling external dependencies : see the [package manager](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/upm-ui.html)